# Cookie without the secure flag jboss 5.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cookies, jboss, jboss5.x

Hello there..

```
  I am trying to fixing Cookie without the secure flag in jboss 5.1

  <myJBossServerInstancePath>/deploy/jbossweb.sar/context.xml
```

```
 and also added 

     response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" +  session.getId() + ";httpOnly");
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + session.getId() + "; secure");
```

still secure flag missing. My project is Jboss 5.1 and java 1.6,Where is my mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open {JBOSS_HOME}/server/SERVER_NAME/deploy/jbossweb.sar/contex.xml

Add `<SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" />`

And restart the server